PANDAS bar graph is empty and missing x and y labels
So I have the following code:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv(r"data.csv")
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
print(df['soda'].value_counts())
dr = pd.read_csv(r"new_data.csv")

plt.title("Favorite sodas in the U.S.")
axis = dr[['soda','number']].plot(kind='bar',title = 'Favorite sodas of the USA')
axis.set_xlabel("soda", fontsize=12)
axis.set_ylabel("number", fontsize=12)
plt.show()

and the following csv file(I dont know how to attach a file so I'll write its contents in code):
soda,number
Coca-Cola , 15
Mountain Dew , 10
Dr.Pepper, 7
Pepsi, 6
Root Beer, 5
Spirte, 2
Kool- Aid, 1
Maple Syrup, 1
Starbucks, 1
Ale80ne, 1
Faygo, 1

As stated in the title, the bar graph is missing its x and y label as well as its contents. Can anyone suggest a fix please?
The graph produced looks like this:
enter image description here
I tried to read stack overflow funnily enough, and I read a post that suggested to do the equivalent of
axis = dr[['soda','number']].plot(kind='bar',ax = 'soda',title = 'Favorite sodas of the USA')

however when I tried to do that I got an Attribute error.

Not able to reproduce your error: https://ibb.co/tQv4Vxg your code gives me the graph linked.

I attached a screenshot of what my graph looks like. Also is there a way to by any chance make the x axis count by sodas instead by 0,1,2,3 (ex. coca-cola, mountain dew, etc.)?

Yes, make soda column index df.set_index('soda', inplace=True) and then axis = dr[['soda','number']].plot(kind='bar',title = 'Favorite sodas of the USA', use_index=True). Maybe you're not seeing anything in the graph because you load your csv in df but you are trying to plot dr?

I can't reproduce your error either. My dtypes for soda and number are obj and int64 respectively.

So it turns out the error was the bar graph was in figure 2 not figure 1 for some reason. When I pressed the - button on the pandas overlay generated by accident, I saw the bar graph I was looking for.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

try after commenting this line
plt.title("Favorite sodas in the U.S.")

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
